# speeding up pandas to sql for writing in several table simultaneously

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am writing about 15 pandas dataframes to postgresql tables. And although they are all small, this operation takes up a few minutes. All the posts I have seen talks about speeding up insert for big load but not about dealing with simultaneous inserts.

Here is what my imports look like so far:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@ipaddress/dbname',
                                connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

tableaudb = tableau.to_sql('dashboard_tableau', engine, if_exists='replace', method='multi')

tren1 = trend.to_sql('dashboard_trend', engine, if_exists='replace', method='multi')

top_sellersdb = top_sellers.to_sql('dashboard_top_sellers', engine, if_exists='replace', method='multi')

etc....
```

I feel like there is gotta be a way to make this more efficient

update: I have been able to modify my uploads to be file copying rather than inserts:

```
conn = pg.connect(host="hosts",
                         port="port",
                         user="user",
                         password="password",
                         database="mydb",
                         options='-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)


                                )
        cur = conn.cursor()

        output = io.StringIO()

        """gather all the tables """

        tableau = tableau.to_csv(output, sep='\t',header=True, index=False)
        trend = trend.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        old_year = old_year.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        value_classification = value_classification.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        top_sellers = top_sellers.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        df55 = df55.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        supplier = supplier.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        candidatt = candidatt.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        stock_ann = stock_ann.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        stock_negat = stock_negat.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        niveau_service = niveau_service.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
        metrics = metrics.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)

        output.seek(0)

        cur.copy_from(tableau, 'dashboard_tableau', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(trend, 'dashboard_trend', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(old_year, 'dashboard_old_year', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(value_classification, 'dashboard_classification', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(top_sellers, 'dashboard_top_sellers', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(df55, 'dashboard_item', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(supplier, 'dashboard_supplier', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(candidatt, 'dashboard_candidat', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(stock_ann, 'dashboard_stock_anormal', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(stock_negat, 'dashboard_stock_negat', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(niveau_service, 'dashboard_niveau_service', sep=',')
        cur.copy_from(metrics, 'dashboard_metrics', sep=',')

        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
```

however I am getting the error:

```
TypeError at /upload.html
argument 1 must have a .read() method
```

which I dont really understand because the files are changed to csv so should be readable?

I have not been able to implement multiprocessing as suggested, would that be a good update from what I am doing now?

Comment: have you tried parallelising your inserts? something like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for example!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try, as I am a beginning, EVERYTHING takes lots of time

Comment: How small are they?  I wouldn't think they can be very small if they take up several minutes.

Comment: "EVERYTHING takes lots of time"  Are you using a AWS t2.nano instance or something?

Comment: literally between 5 and 500 rows. which seems ridiculously small for me but it takes super long so i am thinking there is something wrong with the way i import them

Comment: no lol I meant to modify my code! i have deployed with aws ec2 t2.micro free tier

Comment: I suppose you got error on `cur.copy_from` ? It accepts file-like object and `DataFrame.to_csv` returns `None or str` according to documentation